# std::function with void return type and templated parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have a

```
template<class R>
class MyClass
{
    public:
        typedef std::function<void (const R)> ...;
};
```

Everything is ok until I try to use MyClass < void >.

In this case compiler expands typedef to

```
typedef std::function<void (void)> ...;
```

and does not want to cooperate.

If void is used as R parameter I want typedef to behave like:

```
typedef std::function<void ()> ...;
```

Since the class is pretty big I prefer type_traits and enable_if-like stuff instead of creating specialization for void.

Comment: something like `make_const<R>::type` with a specialization for `void`?

Comment: The rules changed somewhere around C++11, IIRC. My gut feeling was that this should now compile. But the mismatch with observed reality indicates that this is an *obscure corner case* of the language that you'd better avoid (e.g. difficult to maintain code!), e.g. by explicit specialization for the troublesome case.

Comment: Alternatively, `template<class... Params> class MyClass{ using type = std::function<void(const Params...)>; };` - then you can simply leave the argument list empty when you don't want any parameters.

Comment: Something dirty like `typename conditional<is_void<R>::value, void(), void(typename conditional<is_void<R>::value, int, R>::type)>::type` perhaps. Also note that `void(R)` and `void(const R)` is equivalent, it's the same type.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb except for the corner case where `R` is an array type :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, you may use an helper class:

```
template<class R>
struct MyClassHelper
{
    using function_type = std::function<void (const R)>;
};

template <>
struct MyClassHelper<void>
{
    using function_type = std::function<void ()>;
};
```

And then, in `MyClass`

```
template<class R>
class MyClass
{
public:
    using function_type = typename MyClassHelper<R>::function_type;
};
```